# How to execute netsh command from Golang on Windows

Tags: go, netsh

How to execute

> netsh

command from Golang which requires "run as Admin"?

```
err1 := exec.Command("netsh", "interface ipv6 set privacy state=disable").Run()
fmt.Printf("Exec1 err: %+v\n", err1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `exec.Command("netsh", "interface", "ipv6", "set", "privacy", "state=disable").Run()`

Comment: And then run as Administrator or embedding manifest file into exe file withhttps://github.com/akavel/rsrc

Comment: @AndreyK. `runas`?